Custom docker resitry on ubuntu - 500 error
I'm installed this version of docker registry on UBUNTU server
docker-registry github.com/docker/distribution 2.8.0+ds1
ubuntu version is:
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
this is file configuration of registry under /etc/docker/registry
version: 0.1
log:
  fields:
     service: registry
storage:
  cache:
     blobdescriptor: inmemory
  filesystem:
     rootdirectory: /var/lib/docker-registry
  delete:
     enabled: true
http:
  tls:
     certificate: path
     key: path
  addr: my ip
  headers:
     X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
auth:
  htpasswd:
     realm: basic-realm
     path: my path
health:
  storagedriver:
     enabled: true
     interval: 10s
     threshold: 3

When i try to open registry https://my-ip/v2/_catalog I've got 500 error
Furthermore, is there a way to change default port other then 443/8443? On the same machine I've installed sites.

Well, have you checked your logs?

I didn't find it. I search in /var/log/docker

I read this on other sites journalctl -xu  docker.registry but is empty.

Add other info. When I try to login on registry from the same server, I got that cerificate is valid for main domain e not for subdomain. But in config file I specified a different certificare for registry.
